# How To reset Tick time in Countdowntimer On user Click

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I want to reset Tick time in countdown timer on user click and user click is done in onTick()
event

please Help soon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should cancel The countdownTimer and initiate it with new Tick Time

Answer (score 0):

```
new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish(){
              Application.setContentView(layoutWithTheImage);
     }
  }.start();
```

And the you will set a click listener in the other layout... if you could wait until I will use pc, I'll give you all the code you need